# R data.table - How to join two tables based on partial string match

Tags: r, data.table

I have two tables which I want to "left" join/combine.

table_1 should be merged with table_2 if

1. table_1's date falls between table_2s date_start and date_end
2. table_2's name_family is detected within table_1 name_full
3. table_2's name_first is detected within table_1 name_full

With the tidyverse I solved this in the following way:

```
table_1 <- data.frame(
  date = c("01/06/2021", "02/06/2021", "03/06/2021", "04/06/2021"),
  name_full = c("john smith", "alex huber", "franz müller", "john ammer")
) %>%
mutate(across(contains("date"), lubridate::dmy))

table_2 <- data.frame(
  date_start = c("01/01/2021", "01/01/2022", "01/01/2021"),
  date_end = c("31/12/2021", "31/12/2022", "31/12/2021"),
  name_first = c("john", "alex", "franz"),
  name_last = c("smith", "huber", "ammer")
) %>%
mutate(across(contains("date"), lubridate::dmy))

fn_match_name_first <- function(name_full, name_first) {
    str_detect(name_full, regex(name_first)) }
    
fn_match_name_last <- function(name_full, name_last) {
    str_detect(name_full, regex(name_last, ignore_case=F)) }
    
fn_match_date <- function(datum, name_date_interval) {
      datum %within% name_date_interval
     }

library(tidyverse)
table_2<-table_2 %>%
    mutate(date_interval=interval(date_start, date_end))

library(fuzzyjoin)

table_matched <- table_1%>%
    fuzzyjoin::fuzzy_join(., 
    table_2,
    match_fun=list(
      fn_match_name_first, 
      fn_match_name_last,
      fn_match_date),
    by=c(
      "name_full"="name_first",
      "name_full"="name_last",
      "date"="date_interval"
    ),
    mode="left")

table_matched

        date    name_full date_start   date_end name_first name_last
1 2021-06-01   john smith 2021-01-01 2021-12-31       john     smith
2 2021-06-02   alex huber       <NA>       <NA>       <NA>      <NA>
3 2021-06-03 franz müller       <NA>       <NA>       <NA>      <NA>
4 2021-06-04   john ammer       <NA>       <NA>       <NA>      <NA>
                   date_interval
1 2021-01-01 UTC--2021-12-31 UTC
2                         NA--NA
3                         NA--NA
4                         NA--NA
```

My problem though is that this code is quite slow for my use case (table_1 with around 300 000 rows, table_2 more than 2000; takes around 1 hour). I am looking for something faster and want to give data.table a try. What I am struggling with is how to include a function into a join in data.table. Below, my attempt with matching name_last, which doesn't work.

(Note - I am aware that in my example I could simply split the full name into first and last name etc... my acutal use case is a bit more complicated and this approach is not an option).

```
library(data.table)
dt_1<-as.data.table(table_1)
dt_2<-as.data.table(table_2)

result <- dt_1[dt_2, on = .(str_detect(name_full, name_last)), nomatch = 0L]
```

Grateful for any hint. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show only the mathed records, you can use below code:

```
dt_1<-as.data.table(table_1)
dt_2<-as.data.table(table_2)
dt_2[,name_full:=paste(name_first, name_last, sep=" ")]
#give index for faster join
setkey(dt_1, date, name_full)
setkey(dt_2, date_start, date_end, name_full)

result <- dt_1[dt_2, on = .(name_full==name_full, date>=date_start, date<=date_end) , 
               nomatch = 0L]
```

[image]

Comment: many thanks. unfortunately, the approach doesn't work for my use case since name_full can be accompanied by other, surrounding text.  I need a function detecting the presence/absence of name_first and name_last (regex) in name_full.